# Setting locale failed: force certain locale when connecting through ssh

Tags: ssh, localization

For years I have had a problem with the "Setting locales failed". I now understood the problem. On my local machine, my LC_TIME is set to a custom file ("custom.UTF-8"). This custom file does not exist on any remote machine I connect to. However, through SSH my locale setting is 'exported' and searched for at the remote machine. So that is why I keep getting:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "custom.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

What I want to configure is that the local LC_TIME (or any locale variable) is never exported. I am fine just using the value defined at the remote machine. How should I define this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to "prevent" the exporting of the environment is to overwrite them in your user account on the server side. To do so you can create a `.bashrc` file (or the appropriate initialization file for your shell) and overwrite the unwanted variables.

example minimal `.bashrc` file:

```
unset LC_TIME
```

alternatively set the variable to some sane value:

```
export LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

---

If you *really* want to prevent sending some of environment variables then you will most likely need root access on the client and/or the server machine.

On the client side you can edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and remove or alter the `SendEnv` line. Most distributions today have that set up to send the locale environment variables (`LC_*`).

There is a user config file (`~/.ssh/config`) where you can also set `SendEnv`. But there you can only append to the list from the system config file, not overwrite. That is why you can only truly disable this option when you have root access.

Alternatively, on the server side you can edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (note the extra `d` at `sshd_config`. the `d` stands for daemon) and remove or alter the `AcceptEnv` line. Most distributions today have that set up to accept the locale environment variables (`LC_*`).

Look up the explanations for `SendEnv` in the man page for [ssh_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) and `AcceptEnv` in the man page for [sshd_config](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5).

For the sake of completeness: there is also a `PermitUserEnvironment` in `sshd_config`. As the name says, it allows the user to set up some files which will initialize some variables. If `PermitUserEnvironment` is enabled you can take care of the rest as user, but I have never encountered a system with `PermitUserEnvironment` enabled.

Comment: As a user, you can override `SendEnv` in `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot override `SendEnv`, you can only append to it. See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=369401